# Optimal solution to cross entropy loss in the continuous case

Tags: pr.probability, machine-learning, bayesian-probability

This could be a simple question but I don't have a satisfying answer.

**Setup**. Suppose that we have $K$ different classes, and consider cross entropy loss which maps a probability vector in the probability simplex ($K$-dimensions) and a label $y \in [K]$ to a loss as follows:

$\ell(p, y) = -\log p_y$

Now suppose that we have a discrete random variable $\Phi$, and we want to find $w$ that maps $\Phi$ to probability simplex, and solve the following optimization problem

$\min_w \mathbb{E}[\ell(w(\Phi), Y)]$

We know that, by essentially Gibbs' inequality, the optimal solution $w^*$ must satisfy:

$w^*(r) = \Pr[Y=y\ |\ \Phi=r]$

**My question**. What happens if $\Phi$ is a continuous random variable? What is the characterization of the optimal solution?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\Si}{\Sigma}$
It does not matter whether the random variable (r.v.) $R:=\Phi$ is discrete or continuous or neither; it can be any r.v. whatsoever, with values in any measurable space $(S,\Si)$. Indeed, let $Y$ be any $[K]$-valued r.v. defined on the same probability space as $R$. For each $y\in[K]$, let $g_y\colon S\to\mathbb R$ be a $\Si$-measurable function such that 
$$g_y(R):=g_y\circ R=E(I\{Y=y\}|R)[=P(Y=y|R)], \tag{1}
$$ 
where $I$ denotes the indicator and $E(\cdot|R)$ denotes the [conditional expectation given the r.v.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_expectation_with_respect_to_a_random_variable_2) $R$. So, for each measurable map $w$ from $S$ to the probability $K$-simplex (say $V_K$), 
\begin{align}
E\ell(w(R),Y)&=E\sum_{y\in[K]}\ell(w(R),y)I\{Y=y\} \\
&=\sum_{y\in[K]}E\ell(w(R),y)I\{Y=y\} \\
&=\sum_{y\in[K]}EE(\ell(w(R),y)I\{Y=y\}|R) \\ 
&=\sum_{y\in[K]}E\ell(w(R),y)E(I\{Y=y\}|R) \\ 
&=\sum_{y\in[K]}E\ell(w(R),y)g_y(R) \\ 
&=E\sum_{y\in[K]}\ell(w(R),y)g_y(R) \\ 
&=\int_S P(R\in dr)\sum_{y\in[K]}\ell(w(r),y)g_y(r) \\ 
&=-\int_S P(R\in dr)\sum_{y\in[K]}g_y(r)\ln w(r)_y  \\ 
&=-\int_S P(R\in dr)H_r(w(r)), 
\end{align}
where 
$$H_r(v):=\sum_{y\in[K]}g_y(r)\ln v_y  
$$
for $v\in V_K$. 
So, the minimization of $E\ell(w(R),Y)$ in all measurable functions $w\colon S\to V_K$ boils down to the maximization, for each $r\in S$, of $H_r(v)$ in $v\in V_K$. We can choose the versions of the conditional expectations $g_1(R),\dots,g_K(R)$ of 
$I\{Y=1\},\dots,I\{Y=K\}$ so that these conditional expectations are everywhere nonnegative and sum to $1$. That is, $g_y(r)\ge0$ for all $r\in S$ and $y\in[K]$, and $\sum_{y\in[K]}g_y(r)=1$ for all $r\in S$.

Then it is easy to see that $H_r(v)$ is minimized in $v\in V_K$ if $v_y=g_y(r)$; this is just the [nonnegativity of the Kullback-Leibler divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence#Properties). That is, the risk $E\ell(w(R),Y)$ is minimized in $w$ if for all $r\in S$ and $y\in[K]$ we have 
$$w(r)_y=g_y(r),$$
and $g_y(r)$ could be (generally, only symbolically) written as $P(Y=y|R=r)$ -- cf. (1).

Comment: My question is how is $\Pr[Y=y|R=r]$ well defined for a continuous random variable? According to the common definition of conditional probability, this is $\Pr[Y=y, R=r]/\Pr[R=r] = 0/0$ because $\Pr[R=r] = 0$?

Comment: Ok -- I see that it is indeed $g_y(r)$ and it is only symbolically written as $\Pr[Y=y|R=r]$ so my first comment should be viewed as to confirm that "normally, $\Pr[Y=y|R=r]$ is undefined after all". Second, in your (1) in the bracket $[=\Pr[Y=y|R]]$, for that if we conditioned on $R=r$ would it again be that things are undefined? Finally, you mentioned that "We can choose the versions of the conditional expectations $g_1(R), ..., g_K(R) so that...$ What does that mean? I have no issue with KL divergence part. In fact, my confusion is only about how $\Pr[Y=y|R=r]$ is defined.

Comment: My final question is that I do know a definition of $\Pr[Y=y|R=r]$ via disintegration. See Definition 1.1.23 of https://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2011/08/matrix-book.pdf. If I use that definition, would it be possible to directly work out a proof similar to the discrete case? What is the relationship between that definition and your $g_y(r)$?

Comment: (i) In my answer, $P(Y=y|R=r)$ is **defined** as $g_y(r)$. 
(ii) Concerning 
"We can choose the versions of the conditional expectations $g_1(R),\dots,g_K(R)$ of 
$I\{Y=1\},\dots,I\{Y=K\}$ so that these conditional expectations are everywhere nonnegative and sum to $1$", I am not sure what is unclear to you here. Maybe, "versions"?

Comment: Previous comment continued: If so, note that the conditional expectation is defined only almost surely (a.s.): if $E(Z|X)$ is a (version of the) conditional expectation of $Z$ given $X$, then $E(Z|X)+u(X)$ is also such a version, for any measurable function $u$ such that $u(X)=0$ a.s., and all versions of $E(Z|X)$ are of this form, $E(Z|X)+u(X)$ with $u(X)=0$ a.s. This is somewhat similar to the notion of an antiderivative, where any two different versions of the antiderivative differ just by an additive constant. I have added details on this to the answer.

Comment: Previous comment continued: (iii) The definition of disintegration that you refer to is unclear to me. In particular, the condition that $\Omega_y$ belong to the underlying sigma-algebra seems to be missing there. Also, nothing seems to be said there about the existence of such a disintegration. It only exists under certain conditions (such as the spaces being Radon); see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disintegration_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem .

Comment: Previous comment continued: In my answer, no such conditions are needed: the underlying probability space and the measurable space $(S,\Sigma)$ are absolutely arbitrary. 
Finally, a piece of advice: If you want to use probability, it would be good to learn the notion of the conditional expectation.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the advice :), yes -- I am paging in conditional expectation now -- I am still also curious about the relationship between the conditional expectation you used here and the conditional probability in the book I referred (I know you have given some of your thoughts), both of them are actually almost surely (just a simple observation).

Comment: A disintegration with respect to a r.v. $R$ is a regular conditional distribution given $R$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_conditional_probability#Definition) such that $P(R=r|R=r)=1$ for all $r$. See e.g. Chang and Pollard http://www.stat.yale.edu/~jtc5/papers/ConditioningAsDisintegration.pdf for a rigorous presentation, with many concrete examples. As I said earlier, disintegration exists only under spacial conditions, and it is a more advanced matter than the conditional expectation, and the conditional expectation is used for disintegration anyway.

Comment: Previous comment continued: So, if you really want to learn all of this, first study thoroughly the conditional expectation in a standard course in probability, then read Chang and Pollard's paper. However, as I said, you don't need such an advanced matter as the disintegration and the concomitant conditions for this particular problem of yours. As shown in my answer, the simple conditional expectation works here quite well, and without any special conditions.